# How do I import or load a backup zip file to my H2-database?

Tags: java, database, hibernate, backup, h2

I have to make a web application with Java and with following programs/frameworks: H2, Hibernate, JPA and JSF.

One thing the application have to do is load and store a backup. I managed to make a backup .zip file on my local directory, but I don't know how to load it. I want to load the data to my database, but I found no solution.

I tried this, which I found that would help:

`Restore.execute("../ExampleDirectory/test.zip","../ExampleDirectory/",null);`

But it just unziped my backup file and nothing else happended.

If you got any idea how to do this, please share your knowledge.